# Keras error on Conv2d creation: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to construct a multilayered CNN and I used similar logic to models that I have constructed before, however now when I go to run this it hangs up on the input_shape parameter.

I am using:

```
python 3.6.8
tensorflow 1.11.0
keras 2.1.6-tf
```

I have commented out the input_shape parameter and then the model will construct and compile, but obviously this doesn't make for a usable model. I have tried to make all number a multiple of one another to see if the issue is that the division results in a non-integral number, to no avail.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
import numpy as np


def model():
    new_model = Sequential()
    for i in range(4):
        new_model.add(Conv2D(
                      filters=(3,3), kernel_size = 1
                      , activation='linear', padding='valid'
                      , input_shape=np.array([9,9,9])))

    return cnn_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model()
```

Which results in the following trimmed down stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 19, in <module>
    model()
  File "example.py", line 14, in model
    , input_shape=np.array([9,9,9])))
  File "/home/jb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 426, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
...
  File "/home/jb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 464, in __call__
    fan_in, fan_out = _compute_fans(scale_shape)
  File "/home/jb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 1300, in _compute_fans
    fan_out = shape[-1] * receptive_field_size
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Please let me know if I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [keras doc](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/):

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the batch axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in data_format="channels_last".

So the input_shape is only for the first conv layer. Remove that for all subsequent layer, the shape is automatically calculated.

Edit: Also the argument for `kernel` and `filter` is swapped. Should be

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,Input
import numpy as np


def model():
    new_model = Sequential()

    new_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 1,kernel_size = (3,3),activation = 'linear',padding = 'valid',input_shape = (9,9,3)))
    for i in range(3):
        new_model.add(Conv2D(
                      filters = 1,kernel_size = (3,3)
                      , activation='linear', padding='valid'))
    new_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse')

    return new_model


model().summary()

Model: "sequential_14"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 7, 7, 1)           28        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 5, 1)           10        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 3, 1)           10        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_49 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 1, 1)           10        
=================================================================
Total params: 58
Trainable params: 58
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Just ignore the name, I already had another model loaded in place hence the name of the layer starts at 46.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. While that definitely is an issue with my logic that I fixed, this does not fix the issues mentioned. In fact the error occurs in the first layer anyways.

Comment: I figured out your error. `kernel_size` is the shape of the convolution window, while `filter` is the number of window you would want. So basically swap the argument for filter and kernel_size.

Comment: If that solve your question please accept this answer.